# PHP7 and Apache compilation warnings

Tags: php, c, macos, apache, build-process

When I build php 7.0.1 I had some warnings, I hoped this to be fixed in newer version of php but today I had more warnings with 7.0.2.

## php

6 Warnings were generated by `php_date.c` files

```
/Users/username/folder/php/ext/date/php_date.c:2196:6: warning: absolute value function 'abs' given an argument of type 'long long' but has parameter of type 'int' which may cause truncation of value [-Wabsolute-value] abs(utc_offset / 60),
                                                ^
/Users/username/folder/php/ext/date/php_date.c:2196:6: note: use function 'llabs' instead abs(utc_offset / 60), ^~~ llabs
          6 warnings generated.
```

1 warning generated by `interval.c`

```
/Users/javidgajievi/Ovlee/php/ext/date/lib/interval.c:73:13: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of
      floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
        rt->days = abs(floor((one->sse - two->sse - (dst_h_corr * 3600) - (dst_m_corr * 60)) / 86400));
                   ^
/Users/javidgajievi/Ovlee/php/ext/date/lib/interval.c:73:13: note: use function 'fabs' instead
        rt->days = abs(floor((one->sse - two->sse - (dst_h_corr * 3600) - (dst_m_corr * 60)) / 86400));
                   ^~~
                   fabs
1 warning generated.
```

and 1 warning was generated by pthreads

```
ext/pthreads/src/object.h:41:1: warning: '/*' within block comment [-Wcomment]
/* {{{ */
^
```

## Apache

Apache has generated more warnings so I am going to list only a few of them to give you an idea about the warnings.

```
mod_authnz_ldap.c:554:50: warning: 'ldap_err2string' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.11 - use OpenDirectory Framework
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                      user, r->uri, ldc->reason, ldap_err2string(result));
                                                 ^
/Users/username/folder/apache/include/http_log.h:448:44: note: expanded from macro 'ap_log_rerror'
#define ap_log_rerror(...) ap_log_rerror__(__VA_ARGS__)
                                           ^
/Users/username/ovlee/apache/include/http_log.h:451:63: note: expanded from macro 'ap_log_rerror__'
             ap_log_rerror_(file, line, mi, level, status, r, __VA_ARGS__); \
```

My build configuration

php

```
./configure \
--prefix=/Users/username/fodler/php \
--exec-prefix=/Users/username/folder/php \
--with-apxs2=/Users/username/folder/apache/bin/apxs \
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/Users/username/folder/php/lib \
--with-config-file-path=/Users/username/folder/php/lib \
--disable-all \
--enable-maintainer-zts \
--enable-pthreads
```

Apache

```
./configure \
--prefix=/Users/username/fodler/apache \
--exec-prefix=/Users/username/folder/apache \
--with-pcre=/Users/username/folder/apache/pcre \
--enable-module=so \
--with-mpm=worker
```

So I am not going to list all warning since I think the problem might be causing from my environment which is Mac OSX 10.11.2, xCode 7.2, PHP 7.0.2, APAHCE(Httpd) 2.4.18

What do you think the problem is? how do I fix this warnings?

Comment: Is there some question also?

Comment: Obviously the question is , how do I fix this warnings?

Comment: You want to change/fix the code (and possibly contribute back to the php source repository)?

Comment: I only wish to know the reason of these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

"I only wish to know the reason of these warnings."
Ok, not sure if this will really help you, but here we go .... ;-)

Concerning `/Users/username/folder/php/ext/date/php_date.c:2196:6`:
The code line is

```
abs(utc_offset / 60)
```

where `utc_offset` is declared as `timelib_sll utc_offset`.
`timelib_sll` is defined as

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
typedef uint64_t timelib_ull;
typedef int64_t timelib_sll;
# define TIMELIB_LL_CONST(n) n ## i64
#else
typedef unsigned long long timelib_ull;
typedef signed long long timelib_sll;
# define TIMELIB_LL_CONST(n) n ## ll
#endif
```

in timelib_structs.h and since you're on a mac, _MSC_VER won't be defined and hence timelib_sll is a short long long.
And the compiler complains about a short long long* being passed to a function that expects an int (which is in your case way "smaller" than a long long).

Similar thing with the warning for interval.c:73.

The archive I've downloaded from php.net didn't include a directory ext/pthreads, but the warning message implies that someone has put a comment like

```
/**
lalala
  /* {{{ */
*/
```

in that file and the compiler is complaing about the nested comment block.

Concerning `mod_authnz_ldap.c:554:50: warning: 'ldap_err2string' is deprecated`: apple wants the developers to use another function now. Right now [I don't know](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/OpenDirectoryFramework/index.html) what the replacement would be.
The following two messages (those containing `expanded from macro`) just hint to the source; since it's in a macro expansion it might be difficult to find it otherwise. (Since this looked decidedly like a CLANG warning I've looked it up and, yes: [From Xcode 4.2, Clang is the default compiler for Mac OS X.](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) - so I learned something from this anway ;-))

---

*edit and btw:
the next line is

```
abs((utc_offset % 60)))
```

for which I didn't get a warning; the compiler is smart enough to recognize that something modulo 60 is well within the value range of an int.

Comment: Thank you for your time trying to understand the process but what I was really interested in was the reason of this warnings by that I meant whether these are bugs or something causing from my machine.. but this answer deserves a "vote up".

Comment: Though possible, in this case it has nothing to do with your machine,configuration or setup. And those you've posted seem uncritical for now.

Comment: Yes, despite warnings both php and apache works normally, I just think I should focus on every details of build process.  Thanks again.